# SQL Server 2008 R2 service pack 1 not showing

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update, sql-server-2008

I've checked my SQL server version and it says "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  10.50.1600.1". I've seen [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727) that there's a SP1 for it. Why doesn't windows update offer me to d/l it?
Should I d/l it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some strange reason, the next time I've tried to force a check for updates, 29 updates appeared, including the wanted one.